# SpringMVC 3 - Error in displaying the nested object's property in a <c:forEach> list object

Tags: spring-mvc

i am new for Spring MVC. In my small crm project, i want to display a objectList with nested object. But it show only a object inside objectname like de.fischerlandmaschinen.crm.model.Employee@6018ebcc statt the converted name string.

the below are the codes:

Domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5015685214532097319L;

private Long id;
private String foreignId;

private String title;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
@NotEmpty
private String lastName;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;
@Past
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOfBirth;
@Valid
private Address address = new Address();
@Valid
private Contact contact = new Contact();
private Company company = null; // new Company();
private String notice;

@Past
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date createdDate;
@Past
@Version
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date lastUpdatedDate;
private String status;

private Employee primaryConsultant = null;  //new Employee();
private Employee secondaryConsultant = null;    //new Employee();

public Customer(){
    createdDate = new Date();
    lastUpdatedDate = new Date();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long customerId) {
    this.id = customerId;
}

@Column(name = "foreign_id")
public String getForeignId() {
    return foreignId;
}
public void setForeignId(String foreignId) {
    this.foreignId = foreignId;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Contact getContact() {
    return contact;
}
public void setContact(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

@Column(name = "created_date")
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(Gender gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}
public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE,    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name="company", nullable=true)
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}
public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getNotice() {
    return notice;
}
public void setNotice(String notice) {
    this.notice = notice;
}


@Column(name = "last_updated_date")
public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
    return lastUpdatedDate;
}
public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
    this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
}

//  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="primary_consultant", nullable=true)
public Employee getPrimaryConsultant() {
    return primaryConsultant;
}
public void setPrimaryConsultant(Employee primaryConsultant) {
    this.primaryConsultant = primaryConsultant;
}

//  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="secondary_consultant", nullable=true)
public Employee getSecondaryConsultant() {
    return secondaryConsultant;
}
public void setSecondaryConsultant(Employee secondaryConsultant) {
    this.secondaryConsultant = secondaryConsultant;
}


  }
```

and the Employee Domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String alias;
private String title;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;

    // getter and setter
}
```

In my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "customer/list")
public ModelAndView list() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("customer/list");
    List<Customer> customers = customerService.getAllCustomers();
    mav.addObject("customerList", customers);
    return mav;
}

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, true));

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Gender.class, new GenderEditor());

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Employee.class,
            new CustomEmployeePropertyEditor(employeeService));
}
```

And i have a CustomEmployeePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport for initBinder:

```
@Override
public void setAsText(String text) {
    logger.info("convert string to employee object");

    if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
        setValue(null);
        return;
    }

    Long id = (Long) typeConverter.convertIfNecessary(text, Long.class);

    if (id == null) {
        setValue(null);
        return;
    }

    setValue(employeeService.getEmployee(id));

}

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    logger.info("convert employee object to string");

    Object obj = getValue();
    if (obj == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return (String) typeConverter.convertIfNecessary(
            ((Employee) obj).getLastName(), String.class);
}
    @Override
public void setAsText(String text) {
    logger.info("convert string to employee object");

    if (text == null || text.length() == 0) {
        setValue(null);
        return;
    }

    Long id = (Long) typeConverter.convertIfNecessary(text, Long.class);

    if (id == null) {
        setValue(null);
        return;
    }

    setValue(employeeService.getEmployee(id));

}

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    logger.info("convert employee object to string");

    Object obj = getValue();
    if (obj == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return (String) typeConverter.convertIfNecessary(
            ((Employee) obj).getLastName(), String.class);
}
```

And die JSP Code:

```
<c:forEach items="${customerList}" var="customer">
   <tr>
                <td>${customer.id}</td>
                ...
                <td>${customer.primaryConsultant}</td>
                <td>${customer.secondaryConsultant}</td>

                                    ...
   </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

But i get the unwanted result in Browser:

> de.fischerlandmaschinen.crm.model.Employee@6018ebcc
>         in the field primaryConsultant and secondaryConsultant fields

What is the wrong. And i look for the document of registerCustomEditor. it saids, that it can for the nested path property too. What means the path property? The path in .jsp page or the property in domain object?

thanks

Ludwig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override toString() method in Employee class and write what field values you want to display in the browser. That is the easy way and the only way I can think of right now. :)